# Is it safe to run 'sudo apt autoremove' to uninstall linux-headers and -images?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

How safe is it if I run the suggested command line. Is there a bug?

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  linux-headers-4.15.0-32 linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-33 linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-34 linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Comment: Any reasonable search of the term 'autoremove' on this site, or browsing of `man apt-get` will quickly answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally its totally safe, Ubuntu do "house cleanup" after installation of newer version of kernel by removing all outdaten version prior one you running currently.

If you want to be 100% safe you can wait for reboot, after which you will have latest version of kernel running and then run "sudo apt autoremove" to remove not needed kernels.

In general there is NO point of having multiple version of kernel except you run in problems with your specific hardware with some (latest) kernels.